# Which is better comparison check and why

Tags: javascript

I have a very silly question to understand, Can you please help me with this

I want to do the check as below in javascript, which is better and can you please explain to me why

I am just checking whether my string path contains the value `/` at the last or not

```
  if (!(path.slice(-1) == '/')) {...}
```

OR

```
if (path.slice(-1) != '/'){...}
```

I have gone through all these questions and I didn't get the correct answer 
(I am okay to get downvotes but please answer me :))

[Which is better way? Variables related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170785/which-is-better-way-variables-related)

[Code comparison - Which is better or unnecessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152563/code-comparison-which-is-better-or-unnecessary)

[Which is better in GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720137/which-is-better-in-gwt)

[Which is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090262/which-is-better)

[Which is better Intrinsics or assembly coding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48580457/which-is-better-intrinsics-or-assembly-coding)

Comment: Your question is about whether `x != y` or `!(x == y)` is better? Why would you presume that one is objectively better than the other? I would say neither should be used because both `!=` and `==` are crappy (better to use `!==` and `===`). But aside from that, my preference would be for `x !== y` because it avoids the extra parentheses.

Comment: If the you're debating between two logically equivalent approaches, choose the one that's easier to read. "Not equal" is more easily understood than "Equal, not."

Comment: Here is your answer https://crockford.com/javascript/encyclopedia/#213D%20infix%20operator

Comment: Array.prototype.slice() returns an array. So you're better off with this statement: path.slice(-1)[0] !== '/'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, for comparison it is preferred to use strict comparison operators (i.e., `===` and `!==`) when possible. 
Second, `path.slice(-1) !== '/'` is easier to understand for other people that read your code. Apart from that, these logical operators are equivalent and should have the same performance.